# Bandpass filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a audio file I want to filter it so that i can just have frequency within certain range. I just want signal from 12Khz to 14Khz I want to filter out the other frequency. I tried the butterworth filter in matlab but i dont seem to understand the parameter.

Comment: You may want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710847/designing-a-simple-bandpass-bandstop-filter-in-matlab

Comment: not really this filters out the signal i want to keep the signal and remove everything else.

Answer (score 3):

Have you try:

```
[y,fs]=audioread('audio.audioformat'); 
wn=[12000 14000]/(fs/2);   
[b,a]=butter(n_order,wn);
f=filter(b,a,y);
```

And we divide `wn` by `(fs/2)` because the butter command only accept a
[normalized Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_frequency_%28digital_signal_processing%29)

Comment: Also, `filtfilt` is a good alternative to filter if phase shift is a problem.

Comment: @Adam Watch out for potential numerical issues with the `butter` function. If you want to be on the safe side, [use the zero-pole representation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23665440/2586922) of the filter rather than the coefficient (`b`, `a`) form